# IntersectionObserver not updating in React

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

The following code will trigger a state change as soon as the element enters or leaves the viewport by scrolling

```
const dialog = useRef(),
[visible, set] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((e) => {
            set(e[0].isIntersecting ? true : false)
        }, {root: null, rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0})
        observer.observe(dialog.current)
        return () => observer.disconnect()
    }, [dialog.current])

return <div ref={dialog}>my dialog</div>
```

but if I try something like this

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((e) => {
            set(e[0].boundingClientRect.y <= 0 ? true : false)
        }, {root: null, rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0})
```

the state gets updated only if a re-render is triggered, while I want it to trigger when I scroll the viewport, based on the `boundingClientRect.y` value of the observed element.
the only way I found to make this work is by using `window.onscroll` event inside `useEffect` and putting the observer inside it but it doesn't look too good to me. Is there a different (and better) way than using `window.onscroll` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to do with the DOM content not fully loading by the time the `IntersectionObserver` is instantiated in the `useEffect` hook.

A way around this, without using `window.onscroll`, is to run the hook in a component and pass your setter as a prop.

Something like this

```
function MyObserver({ selector, callback }){
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => callback(entries),
      { root: null, rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0 });

    const element = document.querySelector(selector);

    observer.observe(element);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
      
  }, []);


  return null;
}

function Main() {
  [visible, set] = useState(false);

  return <>
    <div className="myDialog">my dialog</div>
    <MyObserver selector=".myDialog"
      callback={ (e) => { set(e[0].isIntersecting ? true : false); } } />
  </>;
}
```

Now the observer logic is part of the render flow, taking place after the dialog, so it should update correctly.

This worked for me when faced with this exact issue.

Comment: that is a good solution and it works. I wonder if this is more or less resource consuming than window.onscroll

Comment: @soffyo _ Using window.onscroll in the way that you have implemented, a new IntersectionObserver is created every time the state of the DOM element of the dialog is changed. In the way I've expressed, it is only created once and not re-rendered. It's not conditionally rendered either. In terms of which is more performant, I think we may be discussing negligible performance in terms of UX. I don't know how much time it takes for a null-rendering React component to render, but I assume it's not too much more to create an event listener. This is my own opinion though. Up to you to decide.

Comment: Why not only `set(e[0].isIntersecting)` instead of `set(e[0].isIntersecting ? true : false)`?